# VisualForce Email Template - declared 'htmlEmailBody' render as text

Tags: html, visualforce-template

I have a VisualForce Email Template, which includes the '**messaging:htmlEmailBody**' decleration. 
When testing in the preview editor, the template renders the HTML as needed:

[image]

When the Email is sent to an email client (such as Google Mail), the Template renders as Text, and not HTML:

[image]

I am not sure what is missing. 
Please see below the VF Email Template code:

```
    <messaging:emailTemplate subject="[Assignment] Case #{!relatedTo.CaseNumber}: {!relatedTo.Subject}" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Case">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
    <html>
    <style type="text/css">
            body {font-family: arial; size: 12pt;}
            div.card { box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2); transition: 0.3s; border-radius: 5px; background-color: #F8F8F8;}
        </style>
    <body>
    <img src="https://my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=01561000001JYOm&oid=OBFUSCATED"/> <br/>
        The following case was assigned to <b>{!relatedTo.Owner.Name}</b>:
        <br />------------------------
        <br />• Account: {!relatedTo.Account.Name}
        <br />• Contact Name: {!relatedTo.Contact.Name}
        <br />• Case status: {!relatedTo.Status}
        <br />• Priority: {!relatedTo.Priority}
        <br />• Link: https://my.salesforce.com/{!relatedTo.Id}
        <br />• Case #: {!relatedTo.CaseNumber}
        <br />• Reference ID #: {!relatedTo.Thread_Id__c}
        <br />------------------------
        <br />
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!relatedTo.Last_Comment__c!=null}" >
<div class="card">
<b><u>Case Comments:</u></b><br />
<c:SortedCaseCommentsController caseId="{!relatedTo.Id}"/>
</div>
</apex:outputPanel>
<br />
<div class="card">
        <b><u>Case Subject:</u></b><br /> {!relatedTo.Subject}
</div>
<br />
<div class="card">
        <b><u>Case Description:</u></b><br />
        <apex:outputField value="{!relatedTo.Description}" style="white-space:pre;"></apex:outputField>
</div>
<br />
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!relatedTo.Last_Incoming_Email_Content__c!=null}" >
        <br /><b><u>Case Last Incoming Email:</u></b><br />
        <apex:outputField value="{!relatedTo.Last_Incoming_Email_Content__c}" style="white-space:pre;"></apex:outputField>
</apex:outputPanel>        
</body>
</html>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>   
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Thank you, 
Ido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you say the template is rendering as plain text?  The CSS you've written may not be supported by the email client you are viewing the email in.  This would explain the minor styling differences (specifically drop-shadows).

Comment: Thanks DaveCalvin. Do you have any idea on how to get a nice 'card' styled css to play nicely with common email clients, such as gmail?

Comment: A lot of CSS3 is unsupported, see: [link]https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)  You could use an image to mimic a drop-shadow, see: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911656/is-it-possible-to-apply-css3-box-shadows-inline-to-html-e-mails